# Laptop for graphic programming

Tags: laptop

I am looking for a laptop where I can program with CUDA ( so Nvidia is a must ). At the same time I want to make use of Optimus technology. Hence the processors should have a dedicated grapics chip as well. So does the Intel 8th generation already have inbuilt graphics chip?

I am asking this because none of the laptops specifications, that also boasts a Nvidia, specifies inbuilt graphics chip like Intel UHD 620. Under the graphics options, only one graphics chip ( Nvidia ) is seen and not two.

Which laptop is preferable, a U or a HQ or MQ? Is 8th Generation preferable over 7th Generation i7 ?

Most of the work is computer vision programming and matlab stuffs. So, high performance is a must.

The need of two different graphics chip is because, I have experienced that Nvidia itself requires substantial power and hence heats the notebook. In case only the inbuilt graphics card is used for small tasks such as movies etc, the fan should remain calm. Thats my hypothesis and do not know if its true or not.

Suggestions would be highly appreciatd.

Comment: Hi! Your question contains some technical support question which could be considered off-topic for this site. I would focus down your question to your usage case, "CUDA programming", then add a budget and price to minimize chance of closure.

Comment: In general, most consumer grade processors contain integrated graphics. For intel suffixes take a look at the [official processor number guide](https://www.intel.in/content/www/in/en/processors/processor-numbers.html). It specifies U as "Ultra-low power", HQ as "High performance graphics, quad core"